# SonarJS - how to avoid "Non-existent variables should not be referenced" issue

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, sonarjs

I have a JavaScript project that consists of several source files. These files are referenced in `<script>` tags in `index.html` page. There are functions and variables defined in those source files and used in other source files. The problem is that Sonar treats those files as independent and I got

> Non-existent variables should not be referenced (javascript:S3827)

issue. Can anybody help how to avoid this?

Thanks

Pavel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This rule requires configuration. List names of variables and functions shared across files in "sonar.javascript.globals" project property.

Answer (score 0):

If your variable is a global variable, you can choose to invoke the variable from the window object like `window.variable`. Sonarqube will no longer flag that variable as undefined.