# How best to suppress javascript:S3827 when my code uses Microsoft Asp.Net Ajax code?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarjs

Problem: we are wanting to use SonarJS but much of our old Javascript code uses functions from the Microsoft ASP.Net framework (and the MS AjaxToolkit). As such we have a couple of hundred occurrences of the error `"XXX" does not exist. Change its name or declare it so that its usage doesn't result in a "ReferenceError".` (where XXX is Sys, Type, $get etc.).

I appreciate that I could suppress these by specifying them all in the `sonar.javascript.globals` property (as per the Elena Vilchik's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42268346/sonarjs-how-to-avoid-non-existent-variables-should-not-be-referenced-issue) ) but it feels like what I really want to do is to add my own bespoke entries in `sonar.javascript.environments` (called msajax and msajaxtoolkit say). Then I could be more precise about when to include / exclude these globals.

So I guess I would like to know whether defining my own `environment` is supported or if there is a more elegant solutions overall.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are more than welcome to open pull request for https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-javascript. Edit "javascript-frontend/src/main/resources/org/sonar/javascript/tree/symbols/globals.json" by adding new group/groups of names.