# "XXX" does not exist. Change its name or declare it so that its usage doesn't result in a "ReferenceError"

Tags: javascript, configuration, sonarqube

I have been using sonar in my projects. I get that error

`""kendo" does not exist. Change its name or declare it so that its usage doesn't result in a "ReferenceError".`

I know it's about global variables. I saw [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42268346/sonarjs-how-to-avoid-non-existent-variables-should-not-be-referenced-issue/42268501#42268501) answer but I don't understand how to use 'sonar.javascript.globals'.

I searched for documentation and I found [this doc](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarJS). But how to implement? What I'm missing?

Anyone to explain how can I define global variables to sonar? Projects are written with ASP.NET, C#, Javascript.

Comment: Which Scanner do you use to analyze your project? Do you use the command line scanner? Or the Scanner for MsBuild? Or the Scanner for TFS? https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+Source+Code#AnalyzingSourceCode-RunningAnalysis

Comment: I think It is MsBuild. Because we use .NET Projects only. But I don't know how to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the Scanner for MsBuild, add these lines to your `.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <SonarQubeSetting Include="sonar.javascript.globals">
    <Value>kendo,kendo2,etc</Value>
  </SonarQubeSetting>
</ItemGroup>
```

Alternative ways to specify settings are described in the [official documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Additional+Analysis+Parameters).