# SonarQube Reference Error for AEM Source Code Scan

Tags: sonarqube, aem, sonarqube-scan

I would like to enquire on the following problem with regards to the use of AEM functions/APIs in JavaScript files on the front-end. I have encountered some of the following errors such as:

"use" does not exist. Change its name or declare it so that its usage doesn't result in a "ReferenceError".

"pageManager" does not exist. Change its name or declare it so that its usage doesn't result in a "ReferenceError".

The following is one of the issue screenshot as encountered in SonarQube. [SonarQube Blocker Bugs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KP8UW.png)

I have search for applicable solutions but to no avail and tried applying the compliant solution as suggested by SonarQube, however, it does not help as the following variable/function is declared at the backend java code/AEM API, so using 'this.' to reference the variable will result in the variable/function being inaccessible.

I would appreciate if any of you have encountered similar issues from SonarQube Scan previously and may have applied or identified possible solutions for this problem and would like to share. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45859757/xxx-does-not-exist-change-its-name-or-declare-it-so-that-its-usage-doesnt-re) SO question.

Comment: add these variables to `sonar.javascript.globals`

Comment: Thanks for the suggested solutions, may I know how is it possible to use in java maven project?

Comment: you could potentially use this hack, not sure if it will work in the context of server-side js, but you could try: before calling use(), add this `var use = use || {}` this basically sets `use` to itself or an empty object if `use` is not defined. Again. This is a hack to get around the issue. Prefer using the  `sonar.javascript.globals` option, or maybe disabling that JS rule all together?